# Strange graph in tikz

Tags: graphics, nodes, tikz-trees, trees

I want to make a strange graph in tikz. This graph has some nodes inside the nodes... like this figure:
[image]

I tried this:

```
\newcommand{\twonodes}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.7cm]
                                    \node[ circle, fill=gray] (#1) {};
                                    \node[circle, below of=#1](#2) {};
                                    \end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',grow=right, sloped,yscale=1.3,xscale=1.2,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2.6cm, level distance = 1.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance = 1.3cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance = 1cm},
    every node/.style={rectangle, draw=black,thin, minimum size = 0.45cm},
    emph/.style={edge from parent/.style={theme2,ultra thick,draw}},
    norm/.style={edge from parent/.style={white,thin,draw}}]
    \node[norm] {\twonodes{1}{2} }
    child[norm]  { node  (3) {\twonodes{4}{5}}
        child[norm] { node (6) {\twonodes{7}{8}} }
        child[norm] { node (9) {\twonodes{10}{11}} }
    }
    child[norm]   { node (12) {\twonodes{13}{14}}
        child[norm] { node (15) {\twonodes{16}{17}} }
        child[norm] { node (18) {\twonodes{19}{20}} }
    };

    \path (1) edge (12);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I'm getting this strange position on the arrow:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you already some ideas about it?

Comment: For this you should really go with the pic operation.

Comment: Well, you could put nodes on top of other nodes easily enough.  Creating a new shape with named anchors would work if you only want to link to the anchors or the (outer) border. You could also use a macro, or scope.

Comment: I prefer to maintain the tree structure. This picture will be used in a presentation so I will add some transitions.

Answer (score 4):

### Remark

For a version working in PGF version 2.10, please see the bottom of the answer.

Here's a possibility using TikZ and its `pic` path, as **Claudio Fiandrino** suggested in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211891/strange-graph-in-tikz#comment495800_211891):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.pic={
  \node[overlay,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (0,-7.5pt) (-l) {};
  \node[overlay,draw,fill=gray!60,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (0,7.5pt) (-r) {};
  \node[overlay,inner sep=5pt,draw,fit={(-l) (-r)}] (-frame) {};
  },
  ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (Root) {mynode};
\pic[above right=of Root-frame] (L) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of Root-frame] (R) {mynode};
\begin{scope}[node distance=5pt and 1cm]
\pic[above right=of L-frame] (LL) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of L-frame] (LR) {mynode};
\pic[above right=of R-frame] (RL) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of R-frame] (RR) {mynode};
\end{scope}
\foreach \Nodoi/\Nodof in {
  Root/L,L/LL,R/RL}
{
\draw[ar]
  (\Nodoi-r) -- (\Nodof-frame.west);
}
\foreach \Nodoi/\Nodof in {
  Root/R,R/RR,L/LR}
{
\draw[ar]
  (\Nodoi-l) -- (\Nodof-frame.west);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Update

And here's the same approach showing how it admits overlays in `beamer`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}%
  },
}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.pic={
  \node[overlay,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (0,-7.5pt) (-l) {};
  \node[overlay,draw,fill=gray!60,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (0,7.5pt) (-r) {};
  \node[overlay,inner sep=5pt,draw,fit={(-l) (-r)}] (-frame) {};
  },
  ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[visible on=<1->] (Root) {mynode};
\pic[above right=of Root-frame,visible on=<2->] (L) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of Root-frame,visible on=<2->] (R) {mynode};
\begin{scope}[node distance=5pt and 1cm]
\pic[above right=of L-frame,visible on=<3->] (LL) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of L-frame,visible on=<3->] (LR) {mynode};
\pic[above right=of R-frame,visible on=<3->] (RL) {mynode};
\pic[below right=of R-frame,visible on=<3->] (RR) {mynode};
\end{scope}

\draw[ar,visible on=<2->]
  (Root-r) -- (L-frame.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<3->]
  (L-r) -- (LL-frame.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<3->]
  (R-r) -- (RL-frame.west);

\draw[ar,visible on=<2->]
  (Root-l) -- (R-frame.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<3->]
  (R-l) -- (RR-frame.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<3->]
  (L-l) -- (LR-frame.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Update

For PGF version 2.10, showing the desired structure and admitting overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}%
  },
  ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }
}

\newcommand\twonodes[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[draw,minimum height=30pt,minimum width=15pt] (#1) {};
  \node[draw,fill=gray!60,circle,inner sep=3pt] at ([yshift=-7pt]#1.north) (#1-u) {};
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=3pt] at ([yshift=7pt]#1.south) (#1-l) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  grow=right,
  sloped,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2.6cm, level distance = 1.5cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance = 1.3cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance = 1cm},
  edge from parent/.style={draw=none}
  ]
  \node[visible on=<1->] {\twonodes{Root} }
    child  { node[visible on=<5->] {\twonodes{L}}
        child { node[visible on=<7->] {\twonodes{LL}} }
        child { node[visible on=<6->] {\twonodes{LU}} }
    }
    child   { node[visible on=<2->] {\twonodes{U}}
        child { node[visible on=<4->] {\twonodes{UL}} }
        child { node[visible on=<3->] {\twonodes{UU}} }
    };
\draw[ar,visible on=<2->]
  (Root-u) -- (U.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<3->]
  (U-u) -- (UU.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<4->]
  (U-l) -- (UL.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<5->]
  (Root-l) -- (L.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<6->]
  (L-u) -- (LU.west);
\draw[ar,visible on=<7->]
  (L-l) -- (LL.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And an animation of the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm getting this error:
/tmp/gummi_XAEIPX:15: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/mynod
e/.pic'

Comment: @Thuener you need an updated version of PGF/TikZ: Please update to the most recent version (3.0).

Comment: @Thuener See my updated answer. Note that my solution admits overlays in `beamer`, as you requested in a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gonzalo but I can't install packages on my machine só I have to use 2.0 version.

Comment: @Thuener I see. In some hours I will then provide a version which you can use in PGF 2.10.

Comment: @Thuener Please see my updated answer. I added (the last code) a new version that should work with your PGF version and admits overlay specifications.

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is more clean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\twonodes}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,node distance=0.6cm]
                                    \node[ circle, fill=gray] (#1) {};
                                    \node[circle, below of = #1](#2) {};
                                    \end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,->,>=stealth',grow=right,yscale=1.3,xscale=1.2,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance = 2.6cm, level distance = 1.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance = 1.3cm},
    every node/.style={rectangle, draw=black,thin, minimum size = 0.4cm},
    norm/.style={edge from parent/.style={white,thin,draw}}]
    \node[norm] {\twonodes{1}{2}}
    child[norm]  { node  (3) {\twonodes{4}{5}}
        child[norm] { node (6) {\twonodes{7}{8}} }
        child[norm] { node (9) {\twonodes{10}{11}} }
    }
    child[norm]   { node (12) {\twonodes{13}{14}}
        child[norm] { node (15) {\twonodes{16}{17}} }
        child[norm] { node (18) {\twonodes{19}{20}} }
    };

    \path (1) edge (12)
          (2) edge (3)
          (4) edge (9)
          (5) edge (6)
          (13) edge (18)
          (14) edge (15);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (very badly designed) custom shape, just to illustrate an alternative method which enables the parametrization of the parent anchor according to the number of the child. Only two children are permitted, but each node can use the `circle 1` and `circle 1` keys to specify the style for the inner circles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareshape{twodots}{
\nodeparts{}
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
\anchor{text}{\pgfpointorigin}
\anchor{circle 1}{\pgfpointxy{1/6}{1/4}}
\anchor{circle 2}{\pgfpointxy{1/6}{-1/4}}
\anchor{west}{\pgfpointxy{-1/4}{0}}
\behindbackgroundpath{
  \draw (-1/4,-1/2) rectangle (1/4,1/2);
  \draw [circle 2/.try] (0,-1/4) circle [radius=1/6];
  \draw [circle 1/.try] (0,1/4) circle [radius=1/6];
}
\anchorborder{\pgfgetlastxy\x\y
  \pgfpointborderrectangle{\pgfqpoint{\x}{\y}}{\pgfpointxy{1/2}{1}}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={twodots}, >=stealth,
edge from parent path={ [->, shorten >=.0625cm] (\tikzparentnode.circle \the\tikznumberofcurrentchild) -- (\tikzchildnode.west) },
circle 1/.style={fill=gray!50},
level distance=2cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=5cm/2},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=5cm/4}]

\node {} [grow'=right]
  child { node {} 
   child { node {} 
     child { node {} }
     child { node {} }
   }
   child { node {} }
  }
  child { node {} 
    child { node {} 
      child { node {} }
      child { node {} }
    }
    child { node {} 
      child { node {} }
      child { node {} }
    }
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]